# prevent api to be called from anywhere in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, cors

i have a laravel application on version 5.7 . the problem is that my api is being called from outside of my server and people can easily call my api and send SMS and cause my some amount of charge . now what I want to do is that prevent the api from all locations to be called just my own server . I heard that laravel 7 has the cors configured but I wanted to know if there is any way for laravel 5.7 to do that . i have throttle for my api but it seems that its not working or the atacker changes the ips of servers .
so here is my kernel.php :

```
 'api' => [
            'throttle:1000,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
        'apiThrottle' => [
            'throttle:4,10',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Well one possibility, you change your code to add some new parameter to the call, if the API does not see the new parameter it rejects the request

Comment: You can create a middleware to validate the request IP. But if you want to use CORS, you can use an earlier version of the package that Laravel uses today https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/blob/v1.0.6/composer.json

Comment: You can install https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors/ package. That will create a file called cors.php under config folder.

Comment: will this package prevent the api to be called from any other ip address ?

Comment: you can make it an answer so i try and accept that as answer thanks

Comment: @Farshad I made ir answer long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors/ package. That will create a file called `cors.php` under **config** folder. Follow all the setup instructions, are few.

There you can specifiy which origins are allowed (example)

```
'allow_origins' => [
        'http://127.0.0.1/*',
        'https://127.0.0.1/*',
        'http://localhost/*',
        'https://localhost/*',
    ],
```

Comment: after i accepted your answer i realised that api cant be done with cors.php and what i have to do is to autherise that api some how

Comment: So you have this issue open? Did you install the package I mention? Can you share your cors.php code?